# How do I play splitscreen multiplayer in Titanfall 2?

Tags: xbox-one, titanfall-2

I bought **Titanfall 2** last year (2018) for the Xbox. I have heard and seen on Google that the developers have updated the game to support a four player mode, as well a two player co-op mode. But I don't know how to make my team do this.

I think it supposed to update on its own but if it is it isn’t working right. Please let me know how to play splitscreen?

Comment: The 4 player mode you were referring to sounds like Frontier Defense but I've looked everywhere and found nothing referring to a 2 player co-op mode. Where did you hear about it?

Comment: I read it on google, I’m going to get you a link to the site. So how do I get frontier defense? I don’t see it on my games menu

Comment: I may have been mistaken about the 2 player co-op

Comment: On the front menu under multiplayer you should be able to choose to launch multiplayer or frontier defense. It's also the very right gamemode when you go onto the menu deciding what gamemode you want to play. But as I said in my answer this does not have split screen.

Answer (score 4):

There is no split screen in Titanfall 2. You can however play with your friends in multiplayer if they all have their own consoles.